# What are the latest stable proprietary drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 and NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050 (4gb)?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, launchpad

What are is the **LATEST STABLE proprietary drivers** for UBUNTU **16.04** and NVIDIA
Geforce **GTX 1050** (4gb)? There are simply too many answers which I have compiled below:

1. **Nvidia site** says [450](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/163238/en-us)(450.66) is the latest for GTX 1050 (not
   Ubuntu version specific)

   - download from [Nvidia site](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/135161/en-us) and install
   - apt-get has its own install `sudo apt-get nvidia-\*\*450\*\*`,
2. **Additional drivers** tab in `Software and Updates` only shows version
   `390`

   - **Note:** `graphics-drivers` PPA's have not been added yet.
3. [**launchpad**](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) says `430` (430.40)

   > Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-430` (430.40) Dropped
   > support for Fermi series
   > (https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4656)
4. [**Launchpad**](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) also says old branch for GeForce 10 series (1050) is
   390.129

   > Old long-lived branch release: `nvidia-390` (390.129)
   > For GF1xx GPUs use `nvidia-390` (390.129)
5. [Launchpad here](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) shows overview of packages (scroll down).

   Here the version names contain 16.04 for `430`.
6. [Ubuntu recommended drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#NVIDIA_drivers_provided_by_the_Ubuntu_repositories) shows different version for
   ubuntu. If I go by this then only `384` has supported versions for
   16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

These are some ofthe links I looked into:

[1] --> https://askubuntu.com/a/851144/443958
[2] --> [https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
[3] --> https://askubuntu.com/a/937898/443958
[4] --> [ubuntu 18.04 how do I install drivers for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045241/ubuntu-18-04-how-do-i-install-drivers-for-my-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050)
[5] --> [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user535733 thanks. Can you please tell me a bit more as to why you choose (#2 /390)? . I added the `graphics-drivers` ppa just now `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and I get more options in the `additional drivers` tab such as `410`, `430` etc... with ("open source") on it's side.

Comment: The key to success is simply to go with the Additional Drivers tab recommendations. The Ubuntu Developers worked really hard to make that tab trustworthy and reliable. It only shows options *that are compatible with your hardware* from sources that you already subscribe to. After you add the PPA, then go with the Additional Drivers tab (#2 / 430). If you encounter problems,  downgrade to 410 or 390.

Comment: @user535733 Ok 430 I can start with. Thanks for this :). All Nvidia drivers are proprietary.  Any idea why it says it is "open source" in `additional drivers` tab next to 430? Looks like a [glitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185924/nvidia-vs-nouveau-drivers). I see 430 in and even 440 on [Nvidias website](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us) even.

Comment: @user535733 Looks like it works `nvidia-smi` shows that I am using `430`. Just one followup: When I do `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia` I still see `nvidia-390 deinstall` and `nvidia-430 install`. Is that ok? Can I ignore this?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to say in your circumstance.

Comment: @user535733, thank you very much. Do I need to `sudo apt-get purge nvidia390 nvidia-opencl-icd-390` or something. Or do I just leave it like that?

Comment: Does your system work?

Comment: @user535733 `nvidia-smi` shows 2 processes running (433mb in use with `xorg` and `compiz`), version as 430.64. Reboot seems to have no issues. P.S. I am still trying to get the gpu to work or be recognized with `pytorch and fastai`

Comment: Since your system works, leave the packages alone. Your original issue seems solved. Consider opening a separate question your your application questions.